# What syntax to check if values in one data is also listed in another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, match, addition

I have 2 dataframes: `wd_patients` and `wd_appointments`.

How do I check if all patients in wd_patients are also listed in wd_appointments and vice versa.
And then how can I update these two files such that every patient in one dataset also exists in the other one as well?

Please see the structures of my dataframes below:

```
 str(wd_patients)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   990 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ID                : chr  "QJSkgvEFvP" "UwSKF6tmaG" "TgO3Lo9cR6" "DFDaFnBxU9" ...
 $ Age               : num  63 64 60 76 66 68 69 87 74 85 ...
 $ Gender            : chr  "Male" "Female" "Female" "Female" ...
 $ AppointmentCount  : num  3 3 3 3 5 2 2 2 5 2 ...
 $ TreatmentCompleted: chr  "Yes" "No" "No" "Yes" ...

 str(wd_appointments)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   3473 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ patientID : chr  "IEBQggWteS" "nCOytLO2tK" "Kc7D1GZhqr" "GTyawkFnQn" ...
 $ apptDate  : POSIXct, format: "2022-06-01" "2022-06-01" "2022-06-01" "2022-06-01" ...
 $ apptStatus: chr  "No Show" "No Show" "Cancelled" "Cancelled" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by finding patient ids that are in wd_patients and not wd_appointments and vice versa...

```r
ids1 <- setdiff(wd_patients$ID, wd_appointments$patientID) # ids in wd_patients but not wd_appointments
ids2 <- setdiff(wd_appointments$patientID, wd_patients$ID) # ids in wd_appointments but not wd_patients
```

After that you can decide how you want to synchronize the two data.frames

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(wd_patients, wd_appointments, by = c("ID", "patientID"))
```

This will join `wd_appointments` to `wd_patients` where there is a shared ID.

**EDIT**:

If you want to retain only the rows with matches in both data frames, use `inner_join`.

Comment: What if I wanted to update the existing table such that every patient in one dataset also exists in other dataset.

Comment: Use `inner_join`, see updated answer

Comment: I am getting an error when i try to join

Comment: Error in `left_join()`:
! Join columns must be present in data.
✖ Problem with `ID`.

Comment: Well, why don't you put up your data in **reproducible format** so that we can help you concretely? Using for example `dput(head(YOUR DATA))`

Answer (score 0):

Using the base R you can use 'merge' function and you obtain only those observations which are existing in both datasets.

```
mergedData <- merge(wd_patients, wd_appointments , by.x=c('ID'),
by.y=c('patientID'))
```

If you don't want join other variables from the second data set, then you can use the following code:

```
mergedData <- merge(wd_patients, wd_appointments[,c('patientID')] , 
by.x=c('ID'), by.y=c('patientID'))
```